# Are any big shop tools manufactured in the USA?

Tags: table-saw, jointer, lathe, band-saw, thickness-planer

Where a tool (or any product) is manufactured can be a bit broad, so hopefully this isn't off-topic, but are any of the big woodshop tools (table saw, jointer, band saw, etc) made in the US? Let's not consider accessories like blades, but rather the bulk of the tool itself (motor, table, support structure).

ETA: I'm interested in consumer-grade machines, not industrial.

Comment: I can't cite brands, but certainly some make that claim.

Comment: General International manufactures some of its higher end machines in Canada

Comment: Do you strictly want US manufacturers or also the rest of North America?

Comment: Let's clarify the scope of your question.  Are you interested specifically in consumer-class machines or also industrial machines? Northfield still manufactures their equipment in the USA, but only industrial-class.

Comment: @rob US preferred, but NA is good, too. I just didn't want to ask too broad of a question. I'm thinking more consumer-grade machines

Comment: To be pedantic, "General International" is the offshore manufacturer... "General" is (or at least was a decade ago) the North American one.

Comment: Websearching "jointer made in USA" rapidly found some answers to this... along with the comment that manufactured in USA can mean assembled from foreign-made components. Obviously you could try the same search for the other tools.

Comment: Putting on hold for now since it may be difficult to produce a single conclusive answer.  See meta: http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/340/49

Answer (score 4):

Shopsmith (http://www.shopsmith.com/) is one that comes to mind. http://www.stillmadeinusa.com/tools.html#Woodworking may have others.

Answer (score 1):

Oneway Manufacturing, makers of what are arguably the most coveted and appreciated, (maybe the most expensive, too) wood lathes in the world, claim that all of their employees are in North America. (They are a Canadian company.)

Answer (score 1):

Robust wood lathes. Guaranteed 85% American made. http://www.turnrobust.com/